# How to force the static block running in each test method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I found static block is running only once when I execute multiple JUnit tests. **How can I force it to run for each test method?** I am using latest JUnit 4.8.2

Also, according to xUnit design principle, every method should be totally independent on others. Why static block only be executed once?

```
@Test TestMethod1 () {
       Accounts ac = new Accounts();
       ac.method1(); //kill the thread inside
}

@Test TestMethod2 () {
       Accounts ac = new Accounts();
       ac.method2(); // the thread is no longer available!!
}

class Accounts {
   static {
       // initalize one thread to monitor something
   }
}
```

This even happens when *TestMethod1* and *TestMethod2* are in the different Test Classes.

Comment: if you want something initialized before every @Test is run, do it in a @Before annotated method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

static blocks are only executed on class loading because that is what they are: class initializers.  To have a static block run multiple times would require you to unload the class (not an easy thing to do...).

If you need to use static blocks, you can come up with ways to test them.  Why not unwrap the block into a public (static) method? All you have to do in that world is test the method:

```
 static {
      staticInitMethod();
 }

 public static void staticInitMethod(){
      //insert initialization code here
 }
```

you also might be able to get away with just an ordinary initializer

```
 {//not static
      //insert initialization code here
 }
```

Although, the truth is most code doesn't need to use initializers like this at all.

Edit: Turns out Oracle likes the static method approach http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 4):

> Why static block only be executed once?

Because that is the whole point of static initializer blocks!

Or to put it another way, if you want some initialization code to execute multiple times, put it in a regular constructor or method, or (in a tiny number of cases) a non-static initializer block.

---

In the context of JUnit, the normal way to implement test startup and shutdown code using `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods.

---

If you are trying to unit test the execution of static initialization in your own code, you are in for a rough road I think.  But then, unit testing of code with static state (e.g. singletons) is always difficult ... and that's one of the reasons that people think that static state is a bad idea.

- Consider using a Dependency Injection (aka Inversion of Control) framework instead of singletons.
- Alternatively, consider modifying your singletons / static initialization code to make it easier to test.  For instance, add a static method that allows a test to re-execute the initialization.  (And before you say that this breaks the singleton pattern: yes I know.  You need to choose between design / implementation "purity" and ease of testing.)

Comment: But in Junit framework, every test method should be totally independent of another?

Comment: Each JUnit test class can have its own `startup()` and `shutdown()`.  If you want the test methods to be totally independent, you could put each one in its own class.

Comment: @Stephen, singleton pattern is useful from time to time.

Comment: Yes ... but it also presents serious problems for unit testing.  Many people think that Dependency Injection offers a cleaner alternative to singletons.  Its your choice, but testability is one of the things that is affected by that choice.  You can't have it both ways ...

Comment: @user: If you are dealing with a singleton, then you should have said so.

Comment: @user705414: Correct. However, such independence is only possible to achieve if the code is designed for it. And code that depends on static initializer blocks does not play well with independent unit tests. Possible solution: Move the code from the static initializer to a static method, and call this method from the initializer and from the tests.

Comment: @user: It's nice when you can have your tests be all totally independent of each other – good for tracking down problems – but irritatingly expensive too. If you're using singletons quite a bit, you might be better off using an IoC framework (e.g., Spring) to handle configuration and lifetime management, and that will help with the testing too.

Answer (score 0):

Is the static code for the tests for the class being tested?

If the code is static so the tests can share, then you need to move the code into its own class.  Then either have the test class constructor instantiate a static instance or create a test suite that does the same thing.

If you want each test to stand alone, then move what you are doing in your static block into the setup()/teardown() methods, it's what they are there for.

Answer (score 0):

Static block is executed only once when first time class is loaded into JVM. Junit provide `@Before` annotation which is basically used for required initialization fro test case. This can be used for executing static blocks of class. for example I have following class `Car`

```
    public class Car implements Vehicle{

        private String type = "lmv";    
        static {            
            VehicleFactoryWithoutRefl.getInstance().registerVehicle("car", new Car());
        }
        @Override
        public void moveForward() {
        }

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        @Override
        public Vehicle createVehicle() {
            return new Car();
        }



    }
```

and I want to execute  static block of this class in Junit before creating the car instance. I have to load this class in `setUp()` using `class.forName("package.ClassName")`  Junit code.

```
  public class TestFactory {

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.cg.dp.factory.Car");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Test
        //@Ignore
        public void testFactoryInstanceWithoutRefl() {
            Vehicle v1 = VehicleFactoryWithoutRefl.getInstance().newVehicle("car");
            assertTrue(v1 instanceof Car);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Um... make it *non-static*? You can have instance initializer blocks too (same as static blocks, just without the `static` keyword). But test setup code should actually go into an explicit `setUp()` or `@Before` method.

Comment: I think the point here is to *test* static initialization via JUnit, not to redesign the class being tested. So prove that each static method, when called first (and therefore loading the class and causing the static init), works correctly. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: I need to have a static block to make sure every objects share some common things.

Comment: @user - you don't **have to**.  There are other ways to share common things.